# What does this one line of gcc code means?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, frameworks

`gcc -framework IOKit -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreDisplay -F /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -framework DisplayServices -Wl,-U,_DisplayServicesSetBrightness main.c -o prg3`

Could you please explain what's happening here?

Also I should add that: there is this line of code in my main.c.

```
    extern int DisplayServicesSetBrightness(CGDirectDisplayID id,
                                    float brightness)
                                     __attribute__((weak_import));
```

I'm not familiar with C and compiling it etc. so a detailed explanation would help a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: this link to the [gcc options guidance](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) is one of the web pages that you need to read/understand as it covers the available options for the `gcc` compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the parts of the command one by one:

> `gcc`

In macOS, this actually invokes `clang` unless you have installed another compiler.

> `-framework IOKit`

This says to include the parts of the IOKit framework (such as headers and libraries) in the compilation and linking.

> `-framework ApplicationServices`

This says to include the parts of the ApplicationServices framework.

> `-framework CoreDisplay`

This says to include the parts of the CoreDisplay framework.

> `-F /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`

This says to search for frameworks in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks` as well as the default paths.

> `-framework DisplayServices`

This says to include the parts of the DisplayServices framework.

> `-Wl,-U,_DisplayServicesSetBrightness`

This says to pass `-U` `_DisplayServicesSetBrightness` to the linker. That tells the linker it is okay if `_DisplayServicesSetBrightness` is not defined. Normally, the linker would report an error if a referenced symbol were not defined. With `-U`, it will replace the symbol with zero.

The symbol `_DisplayServicesSetBrightness` as seen by the linker is `DisplayServicesSetBrightness` in C source code. On macOS systems (and some others), the compilers automatically prefix underscores.

> `main.c`

This says compile `main.c` and, since no switches to the contrary were given, to link the result of compilation into an executable file.

> `-o prg3`

This says to put the output in a file named `prg3`.

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed. Could you please add some extra resources on this? what should I search for in order to learn more about these?

Answer (score -1):

This code is not *doing* anything. It simply *declares* an external function.

It explains to the compiler that it can revert to an extern function (probably in a library) called `DisplayServicesSetBrightness` that takes two parameters (the Display ID and a brightness) if needed.

The `__attribute__((weakimport))` part tells the linker that it should use (call) this external function only if it doesn't find anything "better" (i.e. non-weak) with the same name.

Comment: That is not the part the question asks about.

Comment: Thanks but yes this was irrelevant of the question. Question was about the line that starts with gcc.